# How do I execute a sequence of DB2 queries with a loop in the middle of them?

Tags: sql, unix, for-loop, db2

I have been rolling around an issue for a couple of days now. I am converting a Unix script that uses Sybase to run in DB2 instead and there is a loop in the middle of it.

The script contains several temp tables and update statements that are reliant to what came before it... followed by a loop and then a few more temp tables, update statements, etc... before a query at the end that populates the end result and exports it to a spreadsheet.

The issue I have is that I can get the declare, insert, update, and select query blocks to all run together at the same time. However, when I try to run it all at once with the loop in the middle, I get the following error: 
" SQL0104N  An unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following "ssion.min_assessment".  Expected tokens may include:  "JOIN ".  LINE NUMBER=1.  SQLSTATE=42601".

The blocks run fine when ran individually... but I need all of the blocks to run together so I can place them in a unix script to be scheduled.

The structure looks like this:

```
Declare temp_table_a;
Insert into temp_table_a (select ... from <table> where ...);
Declare temp_table_b;
Insert into temp_table_b (select ... from temp_table_a, <table> where ...);
Update temp_table_b set <field> = (select <field> from <table> where ...);
Delete temp_table_b where ...;
Declare temp_table_c;
Declare temp_table_d;
Begin Atomic
   FOR V1 AS
       Select ... From temp_table_b
   DO
       Delete temp_table_c;
       Insert into temp_table_c (select ...);
       Delete temp_table_b Where Exists (Select 1 From temp_table_c);
       Update temp_table_d set <date_field> = temp_table_c.<date_field> where exists (Select 1 from temp_table_b where ...);
       Delete temp_table_c where exists (Select 1 from temp_table_c where ...);
       Insert into temp_table_d Select ... From temp_table_c;
   END FOR; 
END
Declare temp_table_e;
Insert into temp_table_e (select ... from temp_table_d, <table> where ...);
Update temp_table_e set <field> = (select <field> from <table> where ...);
Select ... from temp_table_e;
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to what I can do to get all of the query blocks to run in sequence and include the loop?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to put the declare at the beginning. Then, in order to control the execution you could use a handler and another variable, OR a fetching each row in the FOR.

http://www.sqlpl-guide.com/DECLARE

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use compound SQL statements, then you need to use a different statement terminator.  (The compound statement will always use `;` as the statement terminator).

So using `@` as the statement terminator:

```
Declare temp_table_a@
Insert into temp_table_a (select ... from <table> where ...)@
Declare temp_table_b@
Insert into temp_table_b (select ... from temp_table_a, <table> where ...)@
Update temp_table_b set <field> = (select <field> from <table> where ...)@
Delete temp_table_b where ...@
Declare temp_table_c@
Declare temp_table_d@
Begin Atomic
   FOR V1 AS
       Select ... From temp_table_b
   DO
       Delete temp_table_c;
       Insert into temp_table_c (select ...);
       Delete temp_table_b Where Exists (Select 1 From temp_table_c);
       Update temp_table_d set <date_field> = temp_table_c.<date_field> where exists (Select 1 from temp_table_b where ...);
       Delete temp_table_c where exists (Select 1 from temp_table_c where ...);
       Insert into temp_table_d Select ... From temp_table_c;
   END FOR; 
END @
Declare temp_table_e@
Insert into temp_table_e (select ... from temp_table_d, <table> where ...)@
Update temp_table_e set <field> = (select <field> from <table> where ...)@
Select ... from temp_table_e@
```

Run with `db2 -td@ -f yourfile.sql`.

Alternatively you can change the terminator in-line in your SQL statement IFF you are using the DB2 CLP:

```
declare temp_table_a;
...

--#SET TERMINATOR @

begin atomic
   for v ...
end @

--#SET TERMINATOR ;

declare temp_table_e;
...
```